# Does manager node using ESB cluster no longer supported?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

as i can see that current version of clustering ESB doesn't include configuration with worker and manager nodes - only worker (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile).
Does manager node no longer supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it is not needed. Both nodes work as a manager and worker (so - it is the "worker only node" which is not used).

The trick is to deploy artifacts in both nodes, see https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile#ClusteringtheESBProfile-Deployingartifactsacrossthenodes

I personally prefer using NFS, for stable environments you can deploy the artifacts using a ci/cd tool